# Change top item of css drop down menu depending on page

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a fairly simple all css/html dropdown menu displaying country flags that link off to language versioned pages.  Right now it is static.  I'd like to change it so the flag of the page you are on appears at the top of the menu.  I can't seem to figure out how I can achieve this.  I assume I will need some JS or jquery?

The css:

```
#l_drop{background: #4D8986;height: 24px;width: 52px;border: 1px #62b7b4 solid; float:left; margin: 6px 0 0 7px;}
#l_drop ul{background: #4D8986;list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#l_drop li{float: left;position:relative;}
#l_drop a{display: block;float: left;height: 24px;line-height: 24px;padding: 0;text-decoration: none;}
#l_drop ul ul{display:none;position: absolute;top: 24px;left: -1px;width: auto;margin-top: -1px;border: 1px #62b7b4 solid;border-top: 0;}
#l_drop ul ul li{width:52px;}
#l_drop ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="l_drop">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="english.gif" width="52" height="24" alt="English" border="0" /></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="spanish.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Español" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="french.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Français" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="german.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Deutsch" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="korean.png" width="24" height="24" alt="한국의" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="chinese.png" width="24" height="24" alt="中国的" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="japanese.png" width="24" height="24" alt="日本人" border="0" /></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I can work with this code swap out the top image based on page?  Or would you suggest I rebuild from scratch?  Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a little script to the language pages that just swapped out img SRC and removed the USA flag:

```
$(function () {
    $("img.USA").attr('src', '/german.png');    $(".lang_flagDE").attr('class', 'hideFlag'); });
```

Each image has a class, like .USA - this script changes the SRC of the US flag with the german  and then hides the second instance of the german flag.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this would be done on the server side and not in the client.  If you are serving static files, you should consider changing the codebase to reflect your changes on each individual file.  If you are using a template, I would handle page detection and re-ordering that way.    NOW with that said, if you are looking to do it client side, JS is needed

You can use window.location.href to detect the page you are on. From there, you will get the "l_drop" DIV and then re-write the UL for that particular page. Without actually coding it.

You could have an ARRAY or JSON that represents the collection of flag attributes.  You can move the correct item to the beginning of the array as needed and then call a function that rewrites the UL by looping through the array, and creating a secondary list after the first element, then replaces the HTML within the l_drop DIV id.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I went a little different direction, but got a working solution.